# How to configure Spring errror page in JSON format with web.xml and an error controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller, web.xml

With *Spring 5*, I am currently able to configure an *error page* in `src/main/webapp/web.xml`, i.e. the following configuration is added:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

In this way, the `error.html` will be rendered when there is `Exception` in the *controller*. However, this `error.html` is in *html* format other than the expected *JSON* format.

I tried to make an *error controller* with some code like this:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/handler")
    public class ErrorController {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/errors")
      public String renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG::come to error page");
        return "test error";
      }
    }
```

In the same time configured `error-page` as such:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <location>/handler/errors</location>
</error-page>
```

But the `ErrorController` cannot be invoked.

**Question: How to configure Spring error page in JSON format with web.xml and an error controller?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realized that the servlats are filtered with `/rest/*` through the `servlet-mapping` tag, so the `location` of the `error-page` has to be prefixed with `/rest`, meaning the `error-page` tag should be configured as such:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/rest/errors</location>
</error-page>
```

Correspondingly the controller can be configured like:

```
@RestController
//@RequestMapping(value = "/handler")
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/errors")
    public String renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG::come to error page");
        return "test error";
    }
}
```